# Possible to isolate upgrade from GCM/APNS to FCM on the App Server only without updating mobile apps?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My team has 3 iOS apps and and 1 Android app that all receive push-notifications from the same App Server. The Android app is currently using GCM and the iOS apps are currently using APNS without any middleman. We've like to move to FCM by updating the App Server.

Each of our customers has their own instance of the App Server. Since each customer will upgrade their App Server on their own schedule, this means the mobile apps need to be backwards-compatible. In other words, the mobile apps need to be able to receive push-notifications from either the old App Server using GCM/APNS or the new App Server using FCM.

**Is it possible to isolate the upgrade from APNS to FCM on the back-end only so that we don't have to upgrade the mobile apps?**

In order to answer this question, we think we need to confirm the following:

- That the Android apps are already backwards compatible so that they can already receive both GCM or FCM notifications without any SDK upgrade.
- That the iOS apps can receive APNS notifications from either APNS or APNS-via-FCM.
- That we don't have to integrate the FCM SDK into the iOS apps.

Comment: more importantly, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I reached out to Firebase support about this and they confirmed that we can upgrade to FCM for both iOS and Android by doing back-end changes only. FCM is backwards compatible with GCM so the Android apps and their notification tokens will continue to work. As for iOS, when we receive the notification token on our back-end, then we simply convert to FCM token by calling "batchImport" API and using that FCM token instead to send notifications to our iOS devices. We've developed and tested these changes and they are working great in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to write the update! It answered a question I had

Comment: I'll add one more update since you bring it up. Since GCM is being deprecated, there is now a app-side change that'll need to be made.

1. In Android project, remove reference to com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm
2. In Android project, add reference to com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging
3. In Android manifest file, remove all GCM-related items... for complete details refer to Android documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm